# $.each() on object properties that may be null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects that may or may not be populated with an array in it's properties. Calling $.each(x,function(){}) on a null x results in a type error

```
try{
  var a = {};
  $.each(a.doesnotexist,function(k,v){})
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}
```

I've seen suggestions of using $.extend on an empty object and passing that value to $.each(). Both of these seem to work for me and seem simpler, are there any downsides to either?

```
//some test values, not guaranteed properties are populated
var a = [
  {v: [1,2,3,4,5], w: [1,2,3,4,5,6]},
  {v: [1,2,3,4,5]},
  {w: [1,2,3,4,5]},
  {v: [1,2,3], w: []},
  {v: null}
];

for (i =0; i < a.length; i++) {if (a[i].v) $.each(a[i].v,function(k,v){});}
for (i =0; i < a.length; i++) {$.each(a[i].v||[],function(k,v){});}
```

The second seems cleanest to me.

Comment: The relevant point here is key existence, not `$.each`

Comment: Essentially jQuery (v1.8.2) breaks at line 583 if you call $.each with an undefined value or the null object. `undefined.length` or `null.length` result in a type error. `({}).length` or `([]).length` are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check if a property exists in an object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  if ("v" in a[i]){ 
    $.each(a[i].v, function(k,v) {
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

And, use [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to check against the correct variable type.

```
if ("v" in a[i] && a[i].v instanceof Array) { ... }
```

In contrast to the short-circuit evaluation, this one not susceptible to truthy values.

```
$.each(a[i].v || [], ...);
```

Comment: And what if `a[i].v` exists, but is `null` or `undefined`? That's the problem OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @user1689607, no, that one it is not

Comment: But it opens the door to that error, so why not use something that'll avoid both problems?

Comment: @user1689607, there, I addressed your concerns

Comment: I agree. `a={b:null}; if("b" in a) $.each(a.b,function(){})` I will edit my question to reflect this possibility

Comment: @Alexander: If `a[i].v` is defined with `null` or `undefined`, the `in` test will pass but then `a[i].v instanceof Array` will throw a *TypeError*.

Comment: @user1689607, did you check that?

Comment: @Alexander: It should be in any browser. It's invalid to try to access a property on `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @user1689607, I can't see where is the property accessor. Anyways, I can't see how that'd fail

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking if the Array member was null, but that's not the point of the question. +1 since your solution does work.

Comment: Accepting this answer, my question was not asking for a solution but possible downsides. "susceptible to truthy" values would be one I suppose, although no "truthy" values I tested threw an exception with $.each()

Comment: @Pete, in this case a *truthy* value could be a non-empty string or a non-empty object causing `$.each` to iterate over false positives

Answer (score 0):

You can even shortcut first one to

```
a[i].v && $.each(a[i].v, function(k,v){});
```

`$.each` will put some overhead on plain objects.

My advice is to make a null-safe `for` loop wrapper like this:

```
function nullsafeForEach(arr, fun) {
  var i, len;
  if (!arr || !arr.length || !fun) {
    return;
  }
  for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
    fun(arr[i]);
  };
}
```

And consider to cache `a.length`

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean `undefined`, not `null`. In JavaScript, variables that don't yet have a value are set to `undefined`.

Personally, I like solution #2 best. It's what I would do. However, you should keep in mind that if this is code someone else might be maintaining in the future, it wouldn't hurt to go with method #1. Method #1 is more obvious in what it is doing, and is thus more maintainable by someone who may not be as familiar with the concept of short-circuiting logical operators (e.g. `||`).

Also, method #2 is every-so-slightly slower than method #1, because it needs to instantiate an empty array if `a[i].v` is [falsy](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript). But the overhead is negligible, so unless this is performance-critical or memory-critical code for some reason, you're fine with method #2.

Comment: Good point on the maintainability. If they don't understand short circuiting, they will be in trouble with some of my other code. I'm really just looking for simple way to avoid $.each() throwing errors. Also a good point point on null, but I maybe getting this data from php's json_encode, which might look something like `["A","B",null]` or `{"a":"A","b":"B","c":null}`. I'm tempted to accept you on a first name basis.

Comment: @Pete Haha. Yeah, it sounds like method #2 is the one for you, provided you're cool with the very minor performance and memory impacts. Essentially, you're trading a couple CPU cycles and a couple bytes of memory usage for a couple bytes of file size and +3 to your cool factor.

Answer (score 0):

A different possibility is to filter the first Array.

```
function hasV(item) { return !!item.v; }
function doWork(k, v) { /* do your work */ }

$.each($.grep(a, hasV), doWork);
```

---

Or use native methods to do the same thing.

```
function hasV(item) { return !!item.v; }
function doWork(v, k) { /* do your work */ }

a.filter(hasV).forEach(doWork);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more legible version (uses clear, verbose checks) of what you might want to do

```
for(var i in a)
{
    if(typeof a[i] == 'object' && typeof a[i].v != 'undefined')
    {
        $.each(a[i].v,function(k,v){  });
    }
}
```

You could also check the length of `a[i].v` for good measure if you want to be really good!

Comment: Unfortunately, `typeof null; // 'object'` :-(

Comment: Yes but null.v should be undefined

Comment: `null.anyProperty` is a *TypeError* in JavaScript.